# Power BI: Create a relative column in power query based on the highest value

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

lets say I have the following table:

| Year | Patch | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1.65 | 23.5 |
| 2021 | 1.67 | 21.3 |
| 2021 | 1.70 | 25.5 |
| 2022 | 1.72 | 23.2 |
| 2022 | 1.75 | 21.5 |
| 2022 | 1.79 | 24.5 |
| 2023 | 1.81 | 23 |
| 2023 | 1.84 | 25.5 |
| 2023 | 1.89 | 28.5 |

I want to create a column with a boolean value "new" and "old" in power query based on the year and the patch version. There are many patch versions in a year. The highest one from the year is always "new". But the patch before should be "old".

Like getting a result like this:

| Year | Patch | Value | Patch Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1.67 | 21.3 | old |
| 2021 | 1.70 | 25.5 | new |
| 2022 | 1.75 | 21.5 | old |
| 2022 | 1.79 | 24.5 | new |
| 2023 | 1.84 | 25.5 | old |
| 2023 | 1.89 | 28.5 | new |

Is there a way in power query to get the nearest value based on the latest patch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Patch", type number}, {"Value", type number}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Year"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Year=nullable number, Patch=nullable number, Value=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", (x)=> 
    [ 
    a = Table.FirstN( Table.Sort(x[All],{ {"Patch", Order.Descending}} ),2),
    b = Record.AddField(a{0}, "Patch Type", "new"),
    c = Record.AddField(a{1}, "Patch Type", "old"),
    d = Table.FromRecords({b,c})
    ][d]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Year", "All"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"Year", "Patch", "Value", "Patch Type"}, {"Year", "Patch", "Value", "Patch Type"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

Comment: I could have sworn you did this yesterday

Comment: Lol - definitely feels like groundhog day but this one is slightly different.

Comment: Sry, having a different contraint this time. Tried it with list.max and list.min but couldn't get the second highest value in power query

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new measure to calculate the max for each year and use that measure to create a new column, below are the formulas.
To find the max,

```
MaxPatch = CALCULATE (
    MAX ( [Patch]),
    ALLEXCEPT ( test,test[Year] )
)
```

To calculate the patch type,

```
Patch_type = IF(test[Patch]=[MaxPatch],"New","Old")
```

Please try this.